# Selenium explicit wait throws NoSuchFrame on changing URLs

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I get

```
  File "login-registration.py", line 33, in drv.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page-36"]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/li[6]/a')
  selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message:
```

Here's my code

```
drv = webdriver.Safari()
url = 'http://practice.automationtesting.in/'

drv.get(url)

drv.find_element(By.XPATH, '//li[@id="menu-item-50"]').click()
time.sleep(3)
drv.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="username"]').send_keys(email)
drv.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="password"]').send_keys(paswrd)
drv.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@name="login"]').click()
wait(driver, 20).until(EC.url_to_be('https://practice.automationtesting.in/my-account/'))
locator = (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page-36"]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/li[6]/a')
wait(drv, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator))
```

I thought it should wait for element and then send error message if it's not there, but i get error right after changing pages. Neither wait `url_to_be` nor wait `element_to_be_clickable` seems to be doing anything.

Comment: btw, it i add time.sleep(1) before looking for element it works

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
drv = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'http://practice.automationtesting.in/'

drv.get(url)
drv.maximize_window()
WebDriverWait(drv, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//li[@id="menu-item-50"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(drv, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="username"]'))).send_keys("automatontesting@mailinator.com")
WebDriverWait(drv, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="password"]'))).send_keys("Automation2022!!")
WebDriverWait(drv, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@name="login"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(drv, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page-36"]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/li[6]/a'))).click()
```

As you can see I changed your line: `drv.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page-36"]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/li[6]/a')`  by `WebDriverWait(drv, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page-36"]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/li[6]/a')))`. Why? Because once you click on login your page will change so you need to wait for the next element, if you do `drv.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page-36"]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/li[6]/a')` you are not waiting for that element and your driver will not find it and it will fail with the error you are getting.

Comment: 'File "/login-registration.py", line 33, in login
    wait(drv, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page-36"]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/li[6]/a')))' still error, that line you corrected i used to check the locator

Comment: Can you share the html of that element? We can not see it because that element is only shown once you do login and we can not do login. Because I guess you can not share the credentials. So, can you share what is the html of the page that loads once you do login?

Comment: i can share, email = 'mario@mushking.dom'
paswrd = 'ItsmeMar1o!'

Comment: Code edited, can you try again?

Comment: One more thing, you see a banner from google ads?

Comment: No ads because of ad block, with new code same error but now on wait(drv, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="username"]'))).send_keys("automatontesting@mailinator.com")

Comment: I edited again, not it should work, basically you need to wait for the element you want to use

Comment: ....line 35, in
    WebDriverWait(drv, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="username"]'))).send_keys...  maybe its trying to look in Ad frame, and then its get blocked, so it throws NoSuchFrame?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
url = 'http://practice.automationtesting.in/'

drv.get(url)

drv.find_element(By.XPATH, '//li[@id="menu-item-50"]').click()
# time.sleep(3)
drv.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="username"]').send_keys("email")
drv.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="password"]').send_keys("pwd")
drv.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@name="login"]').click()
locator = (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page-36"]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/li[6]/a')
WebDriverWait(drv, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator)).click()
```

I am assuming your scenario is - logging in and logout, in that case, I am not sure why you are using the below line, its not needed:

```
wait(driver, 20).until(EC.url_to_be('https://practice.automationtesting.in/my-account/'))
```

Comment: still, same error, i tried visible, clickable, presence of element